# Firebug lite-not helping whit position

Tags: css, firebug

for last 3h I am trying to make example from img:
[image]

Full example is http://couchdb.apache.org/

I Inspected code with Firebug lite, and copy it into fiddle so I can relize what am I doing wrong... but its not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/Sooypai/h9apgk4k/1/

HTML is here, and CSS is to long so I wont copy it here. Its on in fiddle

```
<div class="grid leadin">
<div class="wrap">
<img src="http://couchdb.apache.org/image/couch.png" alt=""/>
<ul class="text-block">
<li>
<h1 class="">
<strong>Apache CouchDB</strong>™ is a database</h1>
</li>
<li>
<h1>that uses<strong>JSON</strong>for documents,</h1>
</li>
<li>
<h1>
<strong>JavaScript</strong>for<strong>MapReduce</strong>indexes,</h1>
</li>
<li>
<h1>and regular<strong>HTTP</strong>for its<strong>API</strong>
</h1>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="button-container">
<a class="button" href="#download">
DOWNLOAD
<small class="download-version">Version 1.6.1</small>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I just can't make img and `<ul>` next to each other. Can some one explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you can give me simple examle to excercise it would be greate. I am kind of stuck... Im learning html/css, and it seems i cant build anything except simplest web page with 4-5 divs.

Comment: Next time please concentrate your questions around specific problems.

Comment: yeah, sure :) its just frustrating... feels like Ive learnd to count, and now I have to solve complicated mathematical equation. Thank you for yout time.

Comment: Note that Firebug Lite is not maintained for years. You should either use the 'real' [Firebug (the Firefox extension)](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firebug/) or the developer tools built into the browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot quite some CSS-Rules..  I include all of them in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xjo4qvmc/1/

Of cause you also have to update the relative paths to an absolute path

```css
background: url(http://couchdb.apache.org/image/sprite.png) no-repeat;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @Codesir.  Ill take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `top: 80px;` to the img.

https://jsfiddle.net/h9apgk4k/2/

Also you might want to add a position other than static to the wrap since position:absolute you're using on the img and the text block are relative to the next non-static positioned parent element.